# assign a variable in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am working on the stencil platform on big commerce. this platform uses the handlebars syntax. I need to be able to set a value based on one of the parameters in my URL, more that like the 'window.location.pathname', and i need to be able to access this new variable across the site. I am able to make something work two different ways using regular JavaScript, but i do not want to recreate my script in every place throughout the site. So basically, I could use some help getting one of my 2 vanilla scripts into a handlebars for formatting. What i have that works is shown below:

```
<p id="BrandLogo"></p>
<script>
    var directory = window.location.pathname;
    var branding;
    var str = directory.includes("blackvue");
    if (str === false) {
        branding = value one;
    } else {
        branding = value 2
    }
    document.getElementById("BrandLogo").innerHTML = branding;
</script>
```

or

```
<p id="BrandLogo"></p>
<script>
    var directory = window.location.pathname;
    var branding;
    if (str == '/URL-I-Want-To-Focus-On/') {
        branding = value one;
    } else {
        branding = value 2
    }
    document.getElementById("BrandLogo").innerHTML = branding;
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help if you show us how you are using Handlebars.

Comment: @76484 it is being used as a template engine by a saas company. The handlebars implementation is outside of dlavely's control

Comment: Any particular reason you want it to be in handlebars? This script looks like it will work client side with stencil.

Comment: It will be used within Stencil, and this script will work client side, however I was hoping to have something i could implement on a 'global' level because i wanted to change multiple elements on a page. 
And to your first point, it is being used within a templated system, and it is outside of my control

Answer (score 26):

If you are trying to set and use a local variable within handlebars try something like this:

First, create a helper function named 'setVar':

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
handlebars.registerHelper("setVar", function(varName, varValue, options) {
  options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
});
```

Next, set your variable(s) using the function you created in the first step.

```
{{setVar "greeting" "Hello World!"}}
{{#if some-condition}}
    {{setVar "branding" "Value one"}}
{{else}}
    {{setVar "branding" "Value 2"}}
{{/if}}
```

Finally, use the variable(s) on your page:

```
<div>
  <h1 id="BrandLogo">{{greeting}}</h1>
</div>

document.getElementById("BrandLogo").innerHTML = {{branding}};
```

Comment: So, basically, instead of using a local variable, you suggested to store the value inside of an encapsulated `options.data.root[..]` I was looking for a way to define a local variable in Handlebars.js

Comment: Don't work (at least for my version). It does de job: Handlebars.registerHelper('var',function(name, value, context){
  this[name] = value;
});
Seen in  https://jsfiddle.net/ceej/QUQ82/

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add a serial number inside a nested 'each' or based on a condition inside nested each following helper works good:

```
hbs.registerHelper('serialNo', function (options) {
  var currentSerialNo = options.data.root['serialNo'];
  console.log("############Current serial No is:"+currentSerialNo);
  if (currentSerialNo === undefined) {
    currentSerialNo = 1;  
  } else {
    currentSerialNo++;
  }

  options.data.root['serialNo'] = currentSerialNo;
  return currentSerialNo;
});
```

Now inside your template you can simply use it like:

```
{{serialNo}}
```

Everytime {{serialNo}} is encountered it prints a serial number one greater than before.