# Getting data into script tag from route?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, chart.js, express-handlebars

I have almost everything I need to get everything working just as I want it, I’m only missing one thing.

This is my get request:

```
app.get('/:username/tasks', function (req, res) {

    if (req.session.user === req.params.username) {
        var photo;
        countList = [],
            categoryList = [];

        db.User.findOne({
            where: {
                username: req.session.user
            }
        }).then(function (info) {
            console.log(info.dataValues.picURL);
            photo = info.dataValues.picURL
        })

        db.Tasks.findAndCountAll({
            attributes: ['category'],
            where: {
                UserUsername: req.session.user
            },
            group: 'category'
        }).then(function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                categoryList.push(result.rows[i].dataValues.category);
                countList.push(result.count[i].count);
            }
            console.log(categoryList);
            console.log(countList);
        })

        db.Tasks.findAll({
            where: {
                UserUsername: req.params.username
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
            res.render('index', {
                data: data,
                helpers: {
                    photo: photo,
                    countList: countList,
                    categoryList: categoryList
                }
            })
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
})
```

The “findAndCountAll” function gives me this in return:

`[ 'Health', 'Other', 'Recreational', 'Work' ] [ 5, 1, 1, 1 ]`

Which are exactly the two arrays I need.
The problem is that I need to pass these values into a javascript script tag.
When I send them to index.handlebars with the helper function in “Tasks.findAll” I get the values. The problem is that if I add a script tag and pass the values into that script tag, it doesn’t work.
How else can I get these values into that script tag?
That’s the last piece of the puzzle.

Here is the js file I'm trying to put the data into:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [MISSING DATA HERE],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [MISSING DATA HERE],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
});
```

I wrote in caps where the missing data is in the file.

Any help is much obliged.

Comment: Are you saying to create an object with the arrays as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run all those queries in parallel using `Promise.all` and when all of them done render chart

```
const userPromise =  db.User.findOne({
                       where: {
                         username: req.session.user
                       }
                     });

const tasksWithCountPromise = db.Tasks.findAndCountAll({
                attributes: ['category'],
                where: {
                    UserUsername: req.session.user
                },
                group: 'category'
            }).then(function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    categoryList.push(result.rows[i].dataValues.category);
                    countList.push(result.count[i].count);
                }
                return { countList, categoryList };
            });

const allTasksPromise = db.Tasks.findAll({
                where: {
                    UserUsername: req.params.username
                }
            });

Promise.all(userPromise, tasksWithCountPromise, allTasksPromise)
 .then(([user, tasksWithCount, allTasks]) => {
     res.render('index', {
                data: allTasks,
                helpers: {
                    photo: user.dataValues.picURL,
                    countList: tasksWithCount.countList,
                    categoryList: tasksWithCount.categoryList
                }
            })
   });
```

Comment: I understand everything you did there, but I didn't understand where you rendered the chart. It looks like your code does exactly the same thing as the first block I sent. How do I get the countList and categoryList into the values of the chart?

Comment: @JoshWood in your code everything runs asynchronously, so render block could be called before you have countList and categoryList values, so you cant pass those values to the render function.

Comment: Your second question is how to pass those values to javascript from handlebar template. please have a look on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767910/3283209