# I have a question javascript toggle index

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, toggle

When using event of toggle function in a popup window, I have a question about toggle event.
Toggle event occurs with tableheader + @index.

When i click a tableheader, only rows of tablebody + @ index values ​​are displayed.
When creating an event without @index value, id value is duplicated so that the whole row is not shown.
Help javascript, jquery experts!

[image]

```js
<!-- popup -->
<script id="reqList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#resultList}}
 <div class="BarType header" id="tableheader{{@index}}">
  <a class="close" id="togglebtn{{@index}}" 
                        href="javascript:toggle_pop({{@index}})"></a>
   <span>{{name}}</span>
 </div>
 {{#each rsToAdd}}
  <div class="BarType body" id="tablebody{{@index}}">
   <table class="def_inTB fl" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{id}}">
       {{name}}
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
{{/resultList}}
</script>

<!-- parent -->
function toggle_pop(index){
 $("#tablebody" +index).slideToggle();
 if ( $("#togglebtn"+index).hasClass('open') ){
  $("#togglebtn"+index).addClass('close');
  $("#togglebtn"+index).removeClass('open');
 }else{
  $("#togglebtn"+index).addClass('open');
  $("#togglebtn"+index).removeClass('close');
 }
   
    }
```

Comment: There are still duplicate ids in your code when you combine @index, see tablebody0 is repeated. What exactly you want is not clear. Whenever you click tableheader, do you want to  show/hide all tablebody below that tableheader, e.g. tablebody0 and tablebody1 under tableheader0

Comment: How do I set the index value so that I can retrieve all the body contents in the tableheader?

Comment: Is {{name}} a part of resultList?

Comment: The name of rsToAdd and the name of tableheader are different.

Comment: You can use `{{@../index}}` to get parent tableheader's index and use it to create a class in tablebody. check my answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML document IDs must be unique. That's why always avoid IDs duplications. Use `class` instead of it.

Your script could looks like next:

```
<script id="reqList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#resultList}}
    <div class="BarType header tableheader{{@index}}">
        <a class="close" href="#" onclick="toggle_pop({{@index}})">
            <span>{{name}}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {{#each rsToAdd}}
        <div class="BarType body tablebody{{@index}}">
            <table class="def_inTB fl" >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{id}}">
                            {{name}}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/resultList}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
function toggle_pop(index){ 
     $(".tablebody" +index).slideToggle(); 
}
```

Try to catch `@index` from `#resultList` and place it in each `tablebody` of `rsToAdd`, I mean make it looks like for each `BarType body`:

```
<div class="BarType header tableheader0">  <-- index = 0
...
</div>
<div class="BarType body tablebody0">     <-- here the same 0, etc for 1, 2, others
...
</div>
<div class="BarType body tablebody0">     <-- here the same 0, etc for 1, 2, others
...
</div>
```

Here code snippet that shows you how it should be:

```js
 
function toggle_pop(index){ 
  $(".tablebody" +index).slideToggle(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="BarType header tableheader0">
<a class="close" href="#" onclick="toggle_pop(0)"> 
  <span>qqqqqqq</span>
</a>
</div> 
<div class="BarType body tablebody0">
 <table class="def_inTB fl" >
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="0">
       qqqqqq
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
    
<div class="BarType body tablebody0">
 <table class="def_inTB fl" >
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
       qqq222
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
    
<div class="BarType header tableheader1">
<a class="close" href="#" onclick="toggle_pop(1)"> 
  <span>qqqqqqq</span>
</a>
</div> 
<div class="BarType body tablebody1">
 <table class="def_inTB fl" >
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="0">
       qqqqqq
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
<div class="BarType body tablebody1">
 <table class="def_inTB fl" >
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
       qqq222
    </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed id -> class, but rsToAdd tablebody data index is not change. rsToAdd List size is 2. So index data put tablebody0, tablebody1...

Comment: @MinaKim, I told you `to catch an index of resultList`. See [how to store value into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767910/11607574) and use `@index` from resultList in `#each`. Ex: `{{setVar "resIndex" @index}}` and then `<div class="BarType body tablebody{{resIndex}}">`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a common class for all `tablebody` under `tableheader`. And you can use `{{@../index}}` to access parent's index to make element structure look like

```
<div class="BarType header tableheader0"></div>
        <div class="BarType body tablebody0"></div>
        <div class="BarType body tablebody0"></div>
<div class="BarType header tableheader1"></div>
        <div class="BarType body tablebody1"></div>
        <div class="BarType body tablebody1"></div>
```

Using parents index to create class as below

```
<div class="BarType body tablebody{{@../index}}">
```

And then use class name as selector,

```
function toggle_pop(index){
    $(".tablebody" +index).slideToggle();
}
```