# Handlebars Helper not printing a javascript variable

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

New to handlebars and I can't seem to find a solution online.

I'm using handlebars express.
I want to start debugging with handlebars using console.log cause alert gets annoying.

I'm using the default log handlebars Helper and I'm running this little script.

```
var thingy = "hello"
{{log thingy}}
```

and in my node.js console: it's printing undefined instead of hello.

How come it's not accepting javascript variables, and how do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You can follow the link below which can be helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241022/assign-a-variable-in-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s because don’t read the var declaration, you have to pass it through the render method.